# ITemplate and DataGrid Column in Codebehind

Tags: .net, asp.net, datagrid, itemplate

I have a situation where I need to work with a datagrid and adding columns dynamically in PageInit as the grid has a few conditional requests that it must handle.  I'm moving along easily with BoundColumns, and ButtonColumns, those are easy.  The problem is with the creation of a TemplateColumn via code.  I have found examples out there about creating a custom class that add controls dynamically by creating a class that uses an implementation of ITemplate.  That works, however, I'm struggling with how to databind elements.

In my grid I would have used <%= DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MyValue") %> or similar, but that isn't an option here.  The Container when inside ITemplate doesn't have a data item property either, so I can't bind there.  Anyone have advice or links that might help, I'm just not finding the right things in google.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can attach an event handler to the DataBinding event of the controls you create in ITemplate.InstantiateIn as in [this MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.databinding.aspx). The sender will be the control and the NamingContainer property will be the DataGridItem, which has a reference to the DataItem which you can use to get whatever data you need.

Comment: Awesome!  That is the article I was looking for.  What a major PITA to get this done....

Comment: +1 for useful link, It is also good to take a look at this one http://aspalliance.com/1125_Dynamically_Templated_GridView_with_Edit_Delete_and_Insert_Options.3